# Create IPM.OLE.CLASS Exception item in Outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, mapi, recurring, appointment

I need to create an exception IPM.OLE.CLASS item in Outlook
So need to delete or change one appointment instance of a recurring appointment
Maybe I could not do it correctly, all have IPM.Note class :(
How to make it?

Created a recurring appointment in Outlook and deleted a single entry of it, could not get IPM.OLE.CLASS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To create an exception in MAPI, you first need to modify the recurrence pattern blob to specify a changed exception, you will then need to create an embedded message attachment and specify some properties on both the attachment itself and the embedded message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `IPM.OLE.CLASS` class corresponds to the exception item of a recurrence series. There is no quite an easy way for creating such items from scratch in Outlook. You can set a message class for newly-created and non-saved yet items. Moreover, you need to associate an item with a recurring appointments.

> Created a recurring appointment in Outlook and deleted a single entry of it, could not get IPM.OLE.CLASS

Instead of deleting an entry you can change the time of a specific entry and save it. A raw sketch:

```
 Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern  
 myRecurrPatt.RecurrenceType = olRecursDaily  
 myRecurrPatt.PatternStartDate = #2/2/2023#   
 myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate = #2/2/2024# 
 
 myApptItem.Save  
 
 'Access the items in the Calendar folder to locate  
 'the master AppointmentItem for the new series.  
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)  
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
 Set myApptItem = myItems("Meet with Boss")  
 
 
 'Get the recurrence pattern for this appointment  
 'and obtain the occurrence for 3/12/23.  
 myDate = #3/12/2023 3:00:00 PM#  
 Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern  
 Set myOddApptItem = myRecurrPatt.GetOccurrence(myDate)  
 
 'Save the existing subject. Change the subject and  
 'starting time for this particular appointment and save it.  
 saveSubject = myOddApptItem.Subject  
 myOddApptItem.Subject = "Meet NEW Boss"  
 newDate = #3/12/2023 3:30:00 PM#  
 myOddApptItem.Start = newDate  
 myOddApptItem.Save 
 
 'Release references to the appointment series  
 Set myApptItem = Nothing  
 Set myRecurrPatt = Nothing  
 
 
 'Get the recurrence pattern for the master  
 'AppointmentItem. Access the collection of  
 'exceptions to the regular appointments.  
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
 Set myApptItem = myItems("Meet with Boss")  
 
 Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern  
 Set myException = myRecurrPatt.Exceptions.Item(1)
```